# AWS EC2 small is accessible on and off every few minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have what I believe is route53 DNS problem

[image]

domain is topishare.com.
The EC2 was working fine for weeks. No software/configuration changes made

CPU credit is ok - more than 100

access using public DNS (ec2-35-163-250-189.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com) or IP is ok. access with SSH is ok.

Any Idea? what can be wrong other than AWS infrastructure? and how can I track the source of the problem?

top is ok

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-46-249:~$ top
top - 09:45:08 up 13 days,  1:19,  3 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.02, 0.00
Tasks: 140 total,   1 running, 139 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  2046428 total,  1025364 free,   671184 used,   349880 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  1112132 avail Mem
```

disk space is ok

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            991M     0  991M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M   21M  180M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.8G  2.6G  66% /
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Route53 healthchecks? What kind/type of Route53 healthcheck?

Comment: What type of the healthcheck you're using? If e.g. http then check your http logs first.

Comment: It looks like you may also be using an ELB.  That seems like a relevant detail you might want to mention.